# WebServer Permission problem, Ubuntu & Lighttpd

Tags: security, apache-2.2, permissions, lighttpd

Just setup lighttpd on Ubuntu 9.04, but struggling with the permissions. The website loads fine, as i am using Fast CGI, however my media (Javascript, CSS, Images) wont load.

I enabled the logging option in the config file:

> debug.log-request-handling = "enable"

I get the following in the log file:

> 2009-08-16 02:42:27: (response.c.473)
>   -- handling physical path 2009-08-16 02:42:27: (response.c.474) Path
>   :
>   /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/media/css/style.css
>   2009-08-16 02:42:27: (response.c.520)
>   -- access denied

I then went and checked the permission on all those directories, changed them so www-data group has permission but i still get 403 forbidden errors and errors in the log file.

i ran:

> chgrp -R id:www-data css/
>   chmod -R g+rx css/

and ls -l

```
> id@mysite.com:/var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/media$
> ls -l total 12 drwxr----- 2 id
> www-data 4096 Aug 16 01:59 css
> drwxr----- 2 id www-data 4096 Aug 16
> 02:00 images drwxr----- 3 id www-data
> 4096 Aug 16 02:00 js
```

Tried granting the www-data user rwx permissions as well, and still get forbidden errors.

How can i fix this? 
It's possible that the server is not using the www-data user, how can i check that it's running under this user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Ubuntu package and didn't change things too much, the running process name should be lighttpd and the default user and group names are both www-data.  Check the server.username and server.groupname entries in your config file (/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf) to be certain.

Running `ps -fC lighttpd` should tell you if it is running and the user id that is is running as.  On my system the output looks like

- `rik@mary:/home/rik$ ps -fC lighttpd`
- `UID      PID PPID C STIME TTY     TIME CMD`
- `www-data 667    1 0 03:50 ?   00:00:00 /usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

Everything you want displayed under your document-root should be readable by the www-data user and the directories need to be executable by www-data as well.  To test this you may want to try using find as the user www-data.  The sudo command can help with this.  *`sudo -u www-data find /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/media/css/`* should succeed.  If not try again one step up with *`sudo -u www-data find /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/media/`* and so on until find can return file and directory names.  Once there the run the *chown* and **chmod** commands against that directory without the -R (recursive) flag.  Then test again.

If you are comfortable with all of the files and directories under */var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/media* being readable by anyone, you may want to chmod all the files as 644 and the dirs as 755.  If you have files that need to have the execute bit set this can be a bit more of a problem unless the all have distinctive extensions.  This is done using the -type, -exec, and -name flags like:

1. `chown -R id:www-data /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/media`
2. `find /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/media -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`
3. `find /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/media -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`
4. `find /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/media -type f -name '*.php' -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

   If you don't want lighty to access other files an/or dirs in the tree, you will need to handle things differently.  It is always easier if you keep files you want readable in a different directory from those you want kept out of the public eye.

Comment: Hey man, thanks that worked. And there are no executable files in the /media directory. Though isnt setting 755, the same as using the g+rwx ?

Comment: @ID.  No, 755 = rwxr-xr-x.  rwx = 777.  Also, the permissions on directories don't mean the same thing they do on files.  The chmod manpage explains the differences.

Comment: @ID No, it isn't.   g+rwx changes group permissions to allow the owning group to read, write, and execute a file or directory.  That would make the group permission number 7 not 5.  ls -l would show it as rwx not r-x.  In order to enter a directory you must have permissions to execute it.  

For directories: Read allows you to determine what is in a directory, write allows you to create new files, and execute allows you to use the files and directories underneeth. 

For files the permission labels are pretty much self explanitory.

Comment: That testing procedure with find is a great idea, and will help me to more quickly debug a whole class of problems like this. I have struggled with similar issues before.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the permissions are right?  "drwxr-----" doesn't seem right.  What you probably want is 0755 (rwxr-xr-w) on the directories and 0644 (rw-r--r--) on the files.

Also, www-data looks to be the owner, not the group.

Answer (score 0):

`ps` should be able to tell you the effective user and group used by the lighttpd process:

```
ps -ax -o user,group,pid,comm | grep httpd
```

You can also check in the lighttpd.conf file what "server.username" and "server.groupname" are set to.

A process needs execute access to a directory in order to descend into it. Make sure that any parent directories not owned by the lighttpd user or group have the global execute permission set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add also read and execute permissions to the group (currently they seem to be missing):

`chmod g+rx css media`